# How can i reduce appsize on parse sdk integration ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, frameworks, parse-platform

I added parse sdk framework for push notification, which increased the project size.
Is there a way to reduce the project size on adding external framework?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to notice that parse framework is quite heavy but it won't increase your binary size that much. It's because parse contains several versions for different CPU architecture (armv7, i386, x86...).

So when you build your app, the linker will chose only the appropriate version and your binary file size will only increase by 7MB.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great tips on exactly this question from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html

In short:

- Change your compiler options: **Optimization Level build setting to Fastest, Smallest [-Os];** and the **Strip Debug Symbols During Copy build setting to Yes**
- Target fewer CPU options
- Sanity check your app for junk files
- Keep data out of the app; store it server-side
- Compress your audio
- Use low-res (8-bit) png files where appropriate